# I can't uninstall managed package

Tags: package

We installed a third party application and trying to uninstall but the uninstall button is inactive.  This is a managed package.

I have all the admin permission to download and change appxchange applications as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Often there might be uninstall steps for it as it might need to be removed from profiles, etc. Is there a guide from the supplier or a help email address you can contact?

Comment: Only guidance I got was to click on uninstall link, which there was none.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certain situations where Salesforce will not allow you to uninstall a package because it could interfere with a part of the system that is not being deleted. I've list a few scenarios straight from Salesforce, where an uninstall option is not available.

-You can’t uninstall a package whenever any component in the package is referenced by a component that will not get included in the uninstall. For example:

-When an installed package includes any component on a standard object that another component references, Salesforce prevents you from uninstalling the package. This means that you can install a package that includes a custom user field and build a workflow rule that gets triggered when the value of that field is a specific value. Uninstalling the package would prevent your workflow from working.

-When you have installed two unrelated packages that each include a custom object and one custom object component references a component in the other, Salesforce prevents you from uninstalling the package. This means that you can install an expense report app that includes a custom user field and create a validation rule on another installed custom object that references that custom user field. However, uninstalling the expense report app prevents the validation rule from working.

-When an installed folder contains components you added after installation, Salesforce prevents you from uninstalling the package.

-When an installed letterhead is used for an email template you added after installation, Salesforce prevents you from uninstalling the package.

-You can’t uninstall a package if a field added by the package is being updated by a background job, such as an update to a roll-up summary field. Wait until the background job finishes, and try again.

Comment: Great answer.  I am trying to uninstall one of the managed packages that was installed from previous Salesforce admin.  It is a third part managed app that was customized for our organization.  The consultant and the company that made this app has no documentation of customization they have made. They informed me it will cost more than licenses itself, so just continue to use them since it will be more expensive to uninstall.

Answer (score 8):

I believe there is a case where a package does not have an uninstall link which has nothing to do with dependencies. If the package is a subscription from the AppExchange, I believe you have to cancel the subscription in the checkout page before you can uninstall.

- Navigate to the Salesforce AppExchange website: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/
- Login using the Salesforce CRM credentials for the org you are trying to uninstall the app from.
- Click on your name and select My Account from the drop down menu.
- Next to the application click the Cancel Subscription link.

Fingers crossed

Comment: Yes, I did unsubscribe from subscription and manually deleted the their components that were not allowing me to uninstall through an editor.  I successfully uninstalled the application.