# Missing uninstall link for managed package

Tags: managed-package, uninstall, package-dependency

I'm unable to uninstall a managed package from a customer org, and I suspect it is due to a dependency from some component, as explained in the [Salesforce doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_uninstalling_packages.htm)

[edit] There is no `Uninstall` link next to the package, unlike for other packages

If indeed the link is missing because of some dependencies, how do I find them? Or if there could be another reason for the missing `Uninstall` link -- what could it be?

=== Screenshot ===

[image: List of installed packages -- outlined package has no uninstall link]

Comment: when you will unistall it. Salesforce will give link of all component which are referring thiss package.

Comment: There is not even an uninstall link for this package. I believe that's because for certain dependencies Salesforce will prevent you from even trying to uninstall -- but maybe there is some other reason?

Comment: can you share the screenshot. also try manual search to find dependency.

Comment: I believe that the uninstall link will not be available if another installed package is an extension of it. However, I can't test this theory because I don't have any packages like this laying around that I can test out. Try clicking on the package name and clicking on View Dependencies.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma I've added a screenshot

Comment: @sfdcfox to the best of my knowledge,`Show Dependencies` on the `Package Details` page shows dependencies from the package to other components -- but I'm looking for the reverse. I don't think there's a dependency from another package back to the one I'm trying to delete

Comment: @sfdcfox i have a package which has it's extension and i'm seeing the uninstall link. Probably when we try to uninstall the package it shows dependency.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a similar thread.probably that would be helpful.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo Nice. I learned something today.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is a case where a package does not have an uninstall link which has nothing to do with dependencies. If the package is a subscription from the AppExchange, I believe you have to cancel the subscription in the checkout page before you can uninstall.

- Navigate to the Salesforce AppExchange website: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/
- Login using the Salesforce CRM credentials for the org you are trying to uninstall the app from.
- Click on your name and select My Account from the drop down menu.
- Next to the application click the Cancel Subscription link.

Fingers crossed

Comment: Thanks.   I learned something new today.

Answer (score 2):

Generally Dependencies are those in which components outside of package referring components of package. For eg. A workflow which is referring a field of package or a button which is part of package is added to a layout which is outside of the package.So you just need to find them and remove them one by one.

Tushar has already pointed you how to find the dependencies.

Since your question has been updated i searched this a little bit and found a thread in which OP has quite similar situation like you.
[I can't uninstall managed package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108370/i-cant-uninstall-managed-package/108377)

Maybe this would be helpful for you.